# Entity Framework track of inserts before SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following issue using entity framework. I'm using IOC with my DBContext as instance per request. I want to insert 'Team' objects into my database. In a certain request there is a loop to insert multiple Teams into the database. Before i add it, i check if the team already exists or not. If it doesn't exist, it can be inserted. 
These inserts happen all in the same context and at the end i save my changes (SaveChanges) Now the following issue occurs:

To get my IdbSet i do the following : `_context.Set<TEntity>()`
After an insert of TEntity, the `_context.Set<TEntity>()` doesn't contain my inserted object.. How can i make sure entity framework tracks my insert during the same scope?

EDIT: 
**Example**
First i add my team

```
_context.Set<Team>().Add(entity);`
```

Then i search for it, but it's not in the list

```
_context.Set<Team>().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't contain your inserted object surely you called `_context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity)`

Comment: I edited my post with an example

Comment: is the instance of `_context` the same one for the insert and the search?

Comment: EF doesn't seem to add it to the `_Context.Set<Team>()` immediately, but to find the inserted entity you can use `_Context.Set<Team>().Local.Where(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Set<Team>().Local.Where(...)` to find your inserted objects before comitting the changes to the database.

However, this is just bad design for an ORM (and a typical problem).

You are using an ORM, but still doing the "database thinking", where you are using the `DbSet` as your object collection.

Try to think you were not doing anything database related in this context (think you'd be doing objects and forget for a moment of EF)... you'd probably just have a list of `Team` objects and pass it around while you are working on them (not "querying a database to find them"): well, do it the same way... have a list of objects (which you can retrieve from the database -using EF-, create new on memory, read from disk or whatnot) and pass that list around while you are working on them.

Then use Entity Framework to **persist** the objects, not to **work on them**. Tada, problem solved.

If you think of EF as a "database persisting and retrieving of objects framework", instead of a "set of objects which you do your logic with", you'll save yourself plenty of future problems and caveats (including this one) with usually pretty dirty workarounds.

Comment: Besides of this answer offer a "solution" Set<Team>().Local.Where(...) (which is definitely not recommended) and describe _theorethicaly_ what is the good point, a) This answer do not explain why its "solution" is bad in the _practice_, and do not offer a practical right solution to the issue.

Comment: @g.pickardou I did indeed offer a solution: use the list of objects and pass it around instead of using isolated functions that query the database to find them, then use EF/the `DbContext` to just persist the changes. **To me** (your mileage may vary) that is the correct solution to this problem (at least to the extent on how the problem was explained by the OP)

Comment: thx for your answer, maybe I missed something, then please let me know. However preventing persisting duplicates _within_ one request or even within one session does not prevent us ending with duplicates in the persisted data (which is obviously the point). I explained it my answer in the wrong solution #1 and #2.

Comment: @g.pickardou to me (just personal oppinion), using an ORM is all about abstracting [*as much as possible*] from the database on your code. Using the database engine for logic that should be on your code is IMO the wrong way to go with EF. Not saying you should -not- handle the database errors, but you shouldn't (again IMO) use them to work on the logic... and the more I read the question, the more I think the objects should not be duplicates already when inserting them for the first time.

Comment: @g.pickardou Again, your design goals may vary a lot from mine (or the OPs, for the matter) and it may make sense for you and your design... just not to me, and that's why I wrote this answer

Comment: Web sites are usually have multiple _concurent_ users. Then you _must_ use "Bad solution #2 resolution:" Both transacions and isolation level are available in EF/Connection level, so your abstraction will not hurt. Still must understand the very basic principles of multiprogramming as web sites (and the persistent store) are uses by multiple concurrent users.

Comment: No, not at all. I think we understood the question differently. My belief is that the OP is creating a set of objects which might be duplicated at the time of entity creation (not duplicated in the database), this check should be done before even trying to insert them into the database. And then, when inserting, there should be duplicate and concurrency checks (and transactions if needed, and whatnot), but those should *always* be there, no matter what.

Comment: OK, so you are saying we must have the unique constraint in the DB _plus_ check for duplicates at client side _before_ trying to insert?

Comment: If those are the requirements of the application -and- the data, then yes. It seems they are in this case. Data should be designed with whatever needed constraints in consideration (and enforced by the database engine), but I'd rather have the database engine giving constraint violations as an exception (which should be taken care of), and not as part of my programming logic.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to reflect the concerns about how EF behaves:

Yes this behavior by design. EF query will executed against the DB and not the local context (not saved) entities. Still you can select your *local* context cache in some tricky ways. However I do not recommend that solution.

Proposed solution:

Create a unique key/constraint at server side on your entity. Your SaveChanges will got an exception when you try to insert (or update) a duplicate. There is NO other way to ensure no duplicates except Bad solution #2 *resoulution*

Back to the terminology of you original question, the conceptual answer is: The **SQL Server who tracks your INSERTS in a natural and centralized way.** If the centralized way term makes no sense please, read the two presented bad solutions

Bad solution #1:

The duplicate issue is still valid across request and more: across sessions. You may decide to keep your context instance *across* requests, so the context will contain the prev inserted entities. This is a very bad idea. First of all there is no guarantee that sessions in the past, or current concurrent users will not insert duplicates. We can safely forget this.

Bad solution #2:

This is a dangerous one, because its inappropriate behavior is not so obvious. In your *virgin* session, you first check if the entity is exist, if not you insert. This makes 2 roundtrips to the server if the entity is not existed (usual case I suppose). This is definitely a drawback. But not this is the main problem. The 2 operations are not atomic by default, so after you checked the not existence but before the insert an other session/user can insert the very same entity, so you are ending to insert a duplicate.

*Bad solution #2 resolution:* You can do the check and the update in *one* transaction to make it atomic, but still your connection/transaction isolation level must be in (SQL) SERIALIZABLE isolation level (highest in SQL Server) and this drives us too far, because it is complicated at client side, and has serious performance drawbacks at server side.

Comment: It is in the same scope and request.. i added an example

Comment: OK, still the professional solution is to create a unique key/constraint on the name column, see Bad solution #2

Comment: ok, but i would expect entity framework adds the object to the dbset. Example: first i have 2 teams in my db. In my contextscope i add a team, than i would expect that entity framework returns 3 teams in the same scope. Even if savechanges is not called yet..

Comment: I understand your concern, but I have to say it does not matter how EF handles your case. Even if EF behaved you liked, still the proposed solution is the way.